# kernel:EDAC MC0 spam in dmesg

Tags: linux, dmesg

I have spam in dmesg containing:

```
kernel:EDAC MC0: UE page 0x0, offset 0x0, grain 1073741824, row 3, labels ":": i3200 UE
```

Any idea what suppose to be wrong?

here are loaded modules:

```
# lsmod | grep edac
i3200_edac              3330  0
edac_core              46581  2 i3200_edac
```

edac-util does not show any errors

```
# edac-util -v
mc0: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: csrow0: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow2: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow2: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow2: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow3: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow3: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow3: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow4: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow4: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow4: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow5: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow5: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow5: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow6: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow6: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow6: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow7: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow7: ch0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow7: ch1: 0 Corrected Errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to be a memory error, but not a fatal one.

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/edac_core/parameters/edac_mc_log_ce
```

will prevent the spam on the console until the next reboot.

Basically the ce_errors are short for correctable errors (aka no "defect" outside the ram).

see  [kernel docu about edac](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/edac.txt)
and  [edac wiki](http://buttersideup.com/edacwiki/WhyAmIgettingMemoryErrors)
for more details.

While i may be totally wrong we have a server with this (ECC RAM) and as there are no uncorrectable errors and memdisk did not show any issues either i let it run with the same ram, change the outputting, started monitoring the uncorrectable errors and there was no further issue for us.

Comment: thanks, will accept your answer in 1-2 days, because since I rebooted the server, I do not getting the error.

Comment: I can confirm those messages dissipated when we replaced the RAM

Comment: I've read some manuals, and they state UE is an unrecoverable error, that is, that particular error was a fatal one.